# How to make Select all checkbox work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a jframe inside that i have a jtable that is connected to an sql database , i have added a checkbox column in the jtable that if the user clicks than presses an update button it will update certain columns in the table , on top of the jtable i have put another checkbox and if this is clicked than it should select all the checkboxes , ive tried using mouse click event but i dont know what codes to use for this , So how can i make this work , please help
my codes are below

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class Attendance extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    static JTable table;
    JLabel lblDate;
    JLabel lblNewLabel;
    JCheckBox chckbxSelectAll;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Attendance frame = new Attendance();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Attendance() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        // Customer List
        JLabel lblAttendance = new JLabel("<html><u>Attendance</u></html>");
        lblAttendance.setBounds(231, 11, 143, 25);
        lblAttendance.setFont(new Font("Lucida Calligraphy", Font.BOLD, 20));
        getContentPane().add(lblAttendance);

        // ScrollPane
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(28, 59, 525, 240);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        // Table
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        // Button Update
        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.setBounds(255, 310, 89, 30);
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                UpdateData();

                            //UpdateData(strUserID); // Update Data
                PopulateData(); // Reload Table

            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);

        chckbxSelectAll = new JCheckBox("Select All");
        chckbxSelectAll.setBounds(459, 29, 97, 23);
        chckbxSelectAll.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        chckbxSelectAll.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        chckbxSelectAll.addMouseListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxSelectAll);

        lblDate = new JLabel("");
        lblDate.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblDate.setBounds(28, 35, 136, 13);
        getContentPane().add(lblDate);

        clock();
        PopulateData();
    }

    private void clock()
    {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.JANUARY);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        lblDate.setText("Date :"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"");

    }

    private static void PopulateData() {

        // Clear table
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());

        // Model for Table
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return String.class;
                    case 3:
                        return String.class;
                    case 4:
                        return int.class;
                    case 5:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        table.setModel(model);

        // Add Column
        // model.addColumn("Select");
        model.addColumn("UserId");
        model.addColumn("Name");
        model.addColumn("Date");
        model.addColumn("Attended");
        model.addColumn("Count");
        model.addColumn("Select");

        Connection con = null;
        Statement s = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");

            s = con.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM  Attendance ";

            ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);
            int row = 0;
            while ((rec != null) && (rec.next())) {
                model.addRow(new Object[0]);
                model.setValueAt(false, row, 4); // Checkbox
                model.setValueAt(rec.getString("UserId"), row, 0);
                model.setValueAt(rec.getString("Name"), row, 1);
                model.setValueAt(rec.getString("Date"), row, 2);
                 model.setValueAt(rec.getString("Attended"), row, 3);
                model.setValueAt(rec.getString("Count"), row, 4);

                row++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Update
    private void UpdateData() {

        Connection connect = null;
        Statement s = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Entered");

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");
            System.out.println("Connected");
            s = connect.createStatement();

            String Query2 = "select * from Attendance ";

            rs = s.executeQuery(Query2);

            String id = "";

            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getString(1);
            }
            System.out.println(id);
            //System.out.println(strUserID);
            String sql = "UPDATE Attendance SET Count=(Count+1) where UserId = '" + id + "'";
             s.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Updated");

            String sql2 = "UPDATE Attendance SET Attended=('Present') where UserId = '" + id + "'";
             s.executeUpdate(sql2);
             System.out.println("Done");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        if(e.getSource()==chckbxSelectAll)
        {
            //System.out.println("Select ALL");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to Use Check Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox)

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your mouse clicked event code by below

```
@Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(chckbxSelectAll.isSelected()){

                for(int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++)
                table.getModel().setValueAt(true, i, 5);

            }else{

                for(int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++)
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(false, i, 5);                   
            }       

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a ChangeListener to your selectAll checkbox. Go through your TableModel and for each row call

```
model.setValueAt(true, row, 5);
```

to set value for the last column's cells

Comment: Can u elaborate more , as im still a beginner in java